# Extjs 4.2: get value from the grid

Tags: extjs, summary

So let's say I have this grid

id time

1 10

2 5

3 10

etc..

How do I get the sum of the values under 'time'?

**EDIT**

I tried to get the array of the value from the grid with this code

```
var sel2 = scope.getPlaylistDetailsGrid().data.items;
```

But it says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined

Comment: loop throw store records and sum it? Or use grid summary row?

Comment: how do i use the grid summary row?

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/grid/group-summary-grid.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to display the sum in the grid, then Riku's suggestion of the summary row is perfect. If you need to just get a sum in code, you can check out the store's sum() method: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-sum

Riku's suggestion:

[image]

Comment: I tried it, but it only returns a null. I edited my question with my updated code.

Comment: You have a typo in the example (timefram instead of timeframe)...is that the issue?

Comment: You're right. thank you for pointing that out. But I'm still not getting the summation. :\

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be usefull for others if i point it out as an answer.

You could use summary row, to achieve this behaviour. Here is [example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/grid/group-summary-grid.html)